# Armazenar palavras em um vetor do tipo "char"

Tags: c, array, string, matriz, malloc

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo que retorna a região do CPF que foi informado, porém estou esbarrando no limite de caracteres que uma variável do tipo `char` permite na linguagem C.

Tentei realizar o procedimento de duas maneiras, mas não consegui identificar meu erro em nenhuma delas.

Através de uma Matriz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void origem(int a[10])
{
    int i;
    char regioes[9][60] = {
        'Rio Grande do Sul',
        'Regiao Centro-Oeste',
        'Regiao Norte',
        'Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui',
        'Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte',
        'Bahia e Sergipe',
        'Minas Gerais',
        'Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo',
        'Sao Paulo',
        'Parana e Santa Catarina'};

    printf("\nOrigem do CPF: ");

    for (i = 0; regioes[a[8]][i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", regioes[a[8]][i]);
    }
}

int main(){
                
    int cpf[10] = {5, 2, 9, 9, 8, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5}; 
    origem(cpf);

return 0;
}
```

E através da função `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void origem(int a[10])
{
    int i;
    char regioes[9];

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        regioes[i] = malloc(60); //aloca espaço uma string de 59 carateres
    }

    regioes[0] = 'Rio Grande do Sul';
    regioes[1] = 'Centro-Oeste';
    regioes[2] = 'Norte';
    regioes[3] = 'Ceará, Maranhão e Piauí';
    regioes[4] = 'Paraíba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte';
    regioes[5] = 'Bahia e Sergipe';
    regioes[6] = 'Minas Gerais';
    regioes[7] = 'Rio de Janeiro e Espírito Santo';
    regioes[8] = 'São Paulo';
    regioes[9] = 'Paraná e Santa Catarina';

    printf("\nOrigem do CPF: %s", regioes[a[8]]);
}

int main()
{
    int cpf[10] = {4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 5, 6, 0, 8, 4, 5};
    origem(cpf);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: A execução fica da seguinte forma]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo que retorna a região do CPF que foi informado, porém estou esbarrando no limite de caracteres que uma variável Char permite na linguagem C

Não, seu problema não está nesse hipotético limite, em nenhum dos dois casos.

Em C o limite de caracteres para uma variável `char`é 1.

### Caso 1

> Através de uma Matriz:

Seu programa tem muitos erros. Vou mostrar alguns e depois uma possível maneira de escrever isso. Assim poderá comparar e tirar suas conclusões.

#### De seu programa

```
void origem(int a[10])
```

A sua função recebe um vetor de 10 `int` e não retorna nada. Quase certamente não era isso o que você queria. Para que vai passar 10 valores? Não seria o caso de passar por simplicidade o CPF como uma string, apenas o valor do dígito que corresponde à região? E o CPF tem 11 dígitos, não 10. E não vai operar com eles, então é mais simples usar `char[11]`.

```
    int  i;
    char regioes[9][60] = {
        'Rio Grande do Sul',
        'Regiao Centro-Oeste',
        'Regiao Norte',
        'Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui',
        'Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte',
        'Bahia e Sergipe',
        'Minas Gerais',
        'Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo',
        'Sao Paulo',
        'Parana e Santa Catarina'};
```

Nunca declare a variável de controle de um loop fora dele sem uma razão séria. Levou uns 10 anos para corrigirem isso na linguagem, mas foi feito há 40 anos.

O separador para as string é `"` e não `'`

```
    for (i = 0; regioes[a[8]][i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", regioes[a[8]][i]);
    }
```

`regioes[a[8]][i]` é um `char` e não um ponteiro.

```
    int cpf[10] = {5, 2, 9, 9, 8, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5};
```

Declarou `cpf` como `int[10]` mas listou 11...

#### Um exemplo

Por simplicidade imagine a função declarada

```
const char* origem(const char*);
```

Porque assim pode chamar de qualquer jeito, por exemplo

```
    printf("Testando com o CPF %s: origem \"%s\"\n",
        "52998224425", origem("52998224425"));
```

e ver

```
Testando com o CPF 52998224425: origem "Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte"
```

Sem declarar mais variáveis.

Porque `const char*` ? Para ficar claro que **não pode** mudar esses valores. A tabela de regiões é estática, fixa, alocada na função. Vocé passa o número do CPF, que a função também não pode mudar, e ela retorna a região. é o comum em C.

#### Eis um teste

```
int main()
{
    char um_CPF[] = { "52998224X25"};

    printf("Testando com o CPF %s: origem \"%s\"\n",
        "52998224425", origem("52998224425"));

    // vai trocar o X
    printf("\nTestando a tabela:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        um_CPF[8] = '0' + i;
        printf(
            "\
CPF\t%s\tOrigem:\t%s\n",
            um_CPF, origem(um_CPF));
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Note que o índice da tabela em C é um inteiro sem sinal, e o CPF foi declarado como um `char[11]`, mais cômodo já que não vai operar com os dígitos. Assim precisa converter o dígito de `char` para `int` para poder acessar a tabela, e essa é a conta `x - '0'` para ter o decimal a partir do `char x`, e `'0'+ d` para ter o `char` a partir do decimal `d`.

#### uma versão de `origem()`

```
const char* origem(const char* cpf)
{
    static const char* regiao[] = 
    {
        "Rio Grande do Sul",
        "Regiao Centro-Oeste",
        "Regiao Norte",
        "Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui",
        "Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte",
        "Bahia e Sergipe",
        "Minas Gerais",
        "Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo",
        "Sao Paulo",
        "Parana e Santa Catarina"
    };
    return regiao[cpf[8]-'0'];
}
```

Note que não precisa declarar o tamanho da tabela: o compilador pode contar isso sozinho. E declarar como `static` é importante porque assim pode usar em `main()` os endereços sem ter que copiar antes de retornar.

#### a saída do exemplo

```
Testando com o CPF 52998224425: origem "Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte"

Testando a tabela:

CPF     52998224025     Origem: Rio Grande do Sul
CPF     52998224125     Origem: Regiao Centro-Oeste
CPF     52998224225     Origem: Regiao Norte
CPF     52998224325     Origem: Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui
CPF     52998224425     Origem: Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte
CPF     52998224525     Origem: Bahia e Sergipe
CPF     52998224625     Origem: Minas Gerais
CPF     52998224725     Origem: Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo
CPF     52998224825     Origem: Sao Paulo
CPF     52998224925     Origem: Parana e Santa Catarina
```

### Caso 2

> através da função Malloc:

A função é `malloc()`

#### Do seu programa

```
void origem(int a[10])
```

Esta é a mesma declaração do primeiro programa e não entendi: a é `int[10]` mas o cpf tem 11 dígitos. E se já tem o vetor dígito a dígito porque não passou apenas o nono dígito? Algo como

```
void origem(int digito)
```

E a declaração de `regioes`

```
    int  i;
    char regioes[9];

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        regioes[i] =
            malloc(60);  // aloca espaço uma string de 59 carateres
    }
```

`regioes` é um vetor de `char`. Fixo. Com 9 `char`. E você tem 10 regiões e elas não são `char`. São `char*` ou `char[]`, vetores.

No `for` deveria declarar `i` e não antes, pela razão que expliquei no início.

`regioes[i]` é um `char`. `malloc()` retorna `void*`, um ponteiro. Não pode escrever isso.

E nem isso

```
    regioes[0] = 'Rio Grande do Sul';
```

O delimitador de string é `"` e não `'`.

```
    printf("\nOrigem do CPF: %s", regioes[a[8]]);
```

E `regioes[ a[8] ]` é um `char`. Não pode usar com o especificador `%s` no `printf()`.

Ao declarar um vetor, prefira o nome singular, porque vai acessar uma ocorrência por vez muito mais do que o grupo como um todo. Então `regiao[0]` a `regiao[9]` é talvez melhor como nome.

#### Um exemplo desse caso

Não consigo ver uma razão para usar `malloc()` num caso desses, porque os valores são uma tabela de valores fixos.

Vou mostrar um exemplo usando a mesma função `origem()`, mas criando um vetor de strings. Essa é a coisa mais comum em C já que o protótipo de `main()` é

```
    int    main( int argc, char** argv );
```

E o sistema monta um vetor de strings com os parâmetros de entrada para **TODO** programa C.

**Montando um vetor de strings com as regiões**

```
    char*  cpf_teste = "12345678X01";
    int    N = 10;
    char** regiao;
```

Então o exemplo vai:

- variar o X lá no CPF de `0` a `9` e mostrar a região usando `origem()`
- criar e carregar o vetor de ponteiros `regiao` com os valores obtidos chamando claro `origem()`
- apagar o vetor alocado

#### Criando o bloco

```
    int    N = 10;
    char** regiao = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 1)
    {
        cpf_teste[8] = '0' + j;  // converte para char
        char* uma    = (char*) origem(cpf_teste);
        regiao[j]    = (char*)malloc((1 + strlen(uma)) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(regiao[j], uma);  // copia
    };  // for()
```

`regiao` é um vetor de ponteiros então incialmente uma área é alocada para eles. E cada um é criado em um loop, variando o dígito do CPF que tem a região e chamando `origem()`. Como a função retorna um ponteiro esse ponteiro é usado para ver o tamanho da string e é então alocado um espaço com um byte a mais para conter o `0` que encerra toda string em C. E uma chamada a `strcpy()` copia a string para o vetor.

Depois o vetor é liberado via `free()` e o programa termina.

#### saída do exemplo 2

```
Testa vetor de 10 strings:

 1  Rio Grande do Sul
 2  Regiao Centro-Oeste
 3  Regiao Norte
 4  Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui
 5  Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte
 6  Bahia e Sergipe
 7  Minas Gerais
 8  Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo
 9  Sao Paulo
10  Parana e Santa Catarina

Apaga tudo

Fim
```

#### O programa completo

A função é a mesma.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* origem(const char* cpf)
{
    static const char* regiao[] = {
        "Rio Grande do Sul",
        "Regiao Centro-Oeste",
        "Regiao Norte",
        "Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui",
        "Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte",
        "Bahia e Sergipe",
        "Minas Gerais",
        "Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo",
        "Sao Paulo",
        "Parana e Santa Catarina"};
    return regiao[cpf[8] - '0'];
}

int main(void)
{
    char*  cpf_teste = "12345678X01";
    int    N = 10;
    char** regiao = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 1)
    {
        cpf_teste[8] = '0' + j;  // converte para char
        char* uma    = (char*) origem(cpf_teste);
        regiao[j]    = (char*)malloc((1 + strlen(uma)) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(regiao[j], uma);  // copia
    };  // for()

    // agora testa
    printf("\nTesta vetor de %d strings:\n\n", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
        printf("%2d  %s\n", 1 + i, regiao[i]);

    // agora apaga o vetor todo
    printf("\nApaga tudo\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
        free(regiao[i]); // apaga as strings
    free(regiao); // apaga o vetor

    printf("\nFim\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você inicializou arrays muito pequenos tanto para o cpf, e tanto para a as regiões, por isso para resolver o problema relatado é só adicionar mais em cada inicialização, como no código abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void origem(int cpf[10])
{
    char regioes[10][60] = {
        "Rio Grande do Sul",
        "Regiao Centro-Oeste",
        "Regiao Norte",
        "Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui",
        "Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas e Rio Grande do Norte",
        "Bahia e Sergipe",
        "Minas Gerais",
        "Rio de Janeiro e Espirito Santo",
        "Sao Paulo",
        "Parana e Santa Catarina"
    };

    printf("\nOrigem do CPF: ");

    // Não sei o que esse código deveria fazer, mas aqui tem um erro de comparação
    for (int i = 0; regioes[cpf[8]][i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", regioes[cpf[8]][i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int cpf[11] = {5, 2, 9, 9, 8, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5}; 
    origem(cpf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Realmente deixei margem para este erro do \0, muito obrigado pelo toque. Porém com este mesmo Array do cpf fiz uma função de validação e funcionou perfeitamente.
Alterei o tamanho deles aqui, mas a execução ainda não apresenta a região.

Comment: Eu não sei a lógica pra saber qual a região de um cpf, apenas resolvi o problema que você apresentou.